# Prove that every odd natural number divides some number of the form $2^n - 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Suppose that $m$ is an odd natural number.

Prove that there is a natural number $n$ such that $m$ divides $2^n -1$.

I have absolutely no idea how to tackle this; any assistance would be welcome.

Comment: This question has been [asked and answered](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555107/pigeonhole-principle-divisibility-proof) recently. A search will undoubtedly give a number of other answers on MSE.

Answer (score 2):

Write the numbers $2, 2^2, 2^3,..,2^{m+1}$. Divide all of them by $m$. By the pigeon hole principle, there are two numbers in this list, lets call them $2^i$ and $2^j$ with $i<j$, which have the same remainder when divided by $m$.

Then

$$m | 2^j-2^i=2^i(2^{j-i}-1) \,.$$

As $m$ is relatively prime to $2^i$ it must divide $2^{j-i}-1$.

**P.S.** For $m \neq 1$, as zero is not a possible remainder, it suffices to look only at $2, 2^2, 2^3,..,2^{m}$, but it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea will be to show that for some power of $n$, $2^n = 1\mod m.$

Here's how I'd start thinking about this problem. Since $m$ is odd, $2$ is not a divisor of $m$, so $2$ is not a zero divisor in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. What does this tell you about the powers of $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$?